# How to create ArrayList of User Defined Class

Tags: c#

I m having a Class suppose Function

I m writing such code

```
class FunctionsList
{

  public ArrayList<Function> functionList // this resuls in error while in Java i have done same
  { 
     get;
     set;
  }
}

while Function class is defined below

public class Function 
{
   public String Name
   {
         get; set;
   }

   public String Signature
   {
         get; set;
   }
}
```

where i m doing wrong in C# pls tell

Comment: List<Function> or IList<Function> or IEnumerable<Function>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I .NET you need to use `List<Function>`. The class [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) only exists in a non generic version and essentially has been superseded by [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: dont worry, we can accept answer only after 10 mins perhaps not before that we can mark it as answered. Anyways Thanks a lot . :)

Answer (score 1):

In C# an ArrayList is an array of objects and doesn't have a generic class.

You might consider using other generic containers as

```
List<T>, 
Collection<T> 
HashSet<T>
```